# Animation of Views at ViewController Load

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am performing an animation when one of my ViewControllers loads. I am calling it in the `viewDidAppear` method. It looks like this.

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2.5f delay:0.0f options:0 animations:^{
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0f relativeDuration:1.0f animations:^{
            CGRect rocketFrame = _rocketImageView.frame;
            rocketFrame.origin.y = rocketFinishPosition;
            _rocketImageView.frame = rocketFrame;

            CGRect flameFrame = _flameImageView.frame;
            flameFrame.origin.y = rocketFinishPosition + rocketFrame.size.height - 3;
            _flameImageView.frame = flameFrame;
            _flameImageView.hidden = false;

            CGRect earthFrame = _earthImageView.frame;
            earthFrame.origin.y = earthFinishPosition;
            _earthImageView.frame = earthFrame;

                CGRect moonFrame = _moonImageView.frame;
                moonFrame.origin.y = moonFinishPosition;
                _moonImageView.frame = moonFrame;
        }];

        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0f relativeDuration:0.6f animations:^{
            _flameImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.f, 1.f);
        }];
    } completion:nil];
```

The issue is when I first load the ViewController, the animation plays but then when finished it snaps back to the starting position. However if I navigate away from the ViewController and back again, the animation plays and the changes persist.

**My Question**

Are my subviews being played out twice?

When can I be certain that my ViewController has finished loading?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming not-autolayout, in the completion block, set the view properties to the final, desired states...

```
// taking the rocket frame as an example:
CGRect rocketFrame = _rocketImageView.frame;  // do this with the other frames, too

[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2.5f delay:0.0f options:0 animations:^{
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0f relativeDuration:1.0f animations:^{

            rocketFrame.origin.y = rocketFinishPosition;
            _rocketImageView.frame = rocketFrame;

            CGRect flameFrame = _flameImageView.frame;
            flameFrame.origin.y = rocketFinishPosition + rocketFrame.size.height - 3;
            _flameImageView.frame = flameFrame;
            _flameImageView.hidden = false;

            CGRect earthFrame = _earthImageView.frame;
            earthFrame.origin.y = earthFinishPosition;
            _earthImageView.frame = earthFrame;

                CGRect moonFrame = _moonImageView.frame;
                moonFrame.origin.y = moonFinishPosition;
                _moonImageView.frame = moonFrame;
        }];

        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0f relativeDuration:0.6f animations:^{
            _flameImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.f, 1.f);
        }];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         // do this with the other frames, too
        _rocketImageView.frame = rocketFrame;
    }];
```